# I can't find FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm new to Android studio and am trying to create a card view that will host data using firebase adapter, but I cannot find it? I hope to place the code in my `onStart` method so I can populate the card, however `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is not appearing (I get the error that it cannot find the symbol). I've added the dependencies and imports, yet it still doesn't appear. Help would be very much appreciated!

Edit
[Here's an image of my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOImC.png)

Comment: can you show us the dependencies

Comment: Please do not use images to convey textual informations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried this dependency?

New Version is now **8.0.0**

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.0'
```